# OpenCL vector types: Can't access unioned components x,y,z with C++11 enabled

Tags: c++, c++11, opencl, unions

The following C++ OpenCL code compiles fine with g++ -c no_x.cpp:

```
// no_x.cpp
#include <CL/cl.h>

void func() {
  cl_double2 xy;
  xy.x = 1.0;
  xy.y = 2.0;
}
```

But with C++-11 enabled the same file gives errors:

```
$ g++ -std=c++11 -c no_x.cpp
nox.cpp: In function ‘void func()’:
nox.cpp:7:7: error: ‘union cl_double2’ has no member named ‘x’
    xy.x = 1.0;
       ^
nox.cpp:8:7: error: ‘union cl_double2’ has no member named ‘y’
    xy.y = 2.0;
       ^
```

I can get around it with xy.s[0], xy.s[1] etc, but that's ugly (which is surely why OpenCL provides the .x, .y components). What's up with C++11 that is causing this? Can I in general not compile OpenCL with C++11?

Comment: xy.s[0] is the most portable way, it is ugly but works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the OpenCL headers (cl_platform.h, included by cl.h), `cl_double2` is defined the following way:

```
typedef union
{
    cl_double  CL_ALIGNED(16) s[2];
#if defined( __GNUC__) && ! defined( __STRICT_ANSI__ )
   __extension__ struct{ cl_double  x, y; };
   __extension__ struct{ cl_double s0, s1; };
   __extension__ struct{ cl_double lo, hi; };
#endif
#if defined( __CL_DOUBLE2__) 
    __cl_double2     v2;
#endif
}cl_double2;
```

So, if your compiler doesn't use the GNU preprocessor, or if `__STRICT_ANSI__` is defined ([g++ may define it](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/C-Dialect-Options.html)), you won't be able to access those members.

Comment: hmmm, I don't know if my version of opencl is older or newer than what you're looking at, but mine is controlled by __CL_HAS_ANON_STRUCT__, and I see earlier in cl_platform.h that that in turn depends on STRICT_ANSI, I guess -std=c++11 defines it.

Comment: @user2387508 `-std=c++11` defines it, but you could simply use the parameter `-U__STRICT_ANSI__` in g++.